# Getting all transaction data from block

Tags: blockchain, javascript

I am thinking about getting all the data from the block which is stored from 1st transaction.

Assume we have done 4 txns from an address to another address
and the data passed/saved in block for each transaction.

Now , i want to retrieve the data of all transaction from 1st to 4th txn (like history of data stored or passed between FROM and TO address or in block).

I tried getting the data from blocks using **BLOCK** and **TRANSACTION** object but it all gives **HASH** and not the raw data.

Currently working using `Javascript,HTML, Geth and web3` for basic implementation.

Suggest if there is any ready API

**UPDATE**

Sample problem

let's assume each txn stores data of firstName and address of some person. *Txn1 - "A" "place1" , Txn2 - "B" "place2" , Txn3 - "C" "place3" , Txn4 - "D" "place4"*.. now w.r.t the txn hash or anything of that kind i need to retrieve - **A place1, B place2, C place3 ,D place4**( the data stored at particular txn)

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum's `getBlock` RPC call has an optional parameter, which if `true`, returns the entire transaction data for each transaction not just the hashes.

Comment: this should be accepted as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/get-history-of-transactions-to-specific-account/21461#21461).

Assuming that you are using Parity, they provide a number of 'trace' APIs which allow you to get information on transactions contained within specific blocks, and sent to/from specific addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

https://medium.com/block-16/ethereum-block-transaction-info-via-aggregated-views-api-by-block-16-aa9b175da929

All you need is:

https://api.block16.io/v1/block/{block number}

change {block number} with the actual block number.

Comment: We don't get "RAW" data in this case..we get details from the block metadata.  we get --from,to,value--
Assume we have stored form data( mail Id, Address, Phone etc) ..can this data be read in "RAW" format ?